# UIAppearance modifier is ignored on iOS 13 when pushed to a new UIViewController

Tags: ios13, uiappearance

We set the `UIAppearance` of our `UIBarButtonItem`s for the whole app like this:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UINavigationBar class]]] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[[UINavigationBar class]]] setTitleTextAttributes:attributes forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

This has worked just fine up until iOS 13.

In the GIF below the first `UIViewController` is loaded and the Cancel button is displayed correctly. I then push to the next screen and the Back button is showed without the appearance changes. When I hit the back button the previous screen is shown with the Cancel button now also incorrectly.

[image]

If I reload the first screen the Cancel button is shown correctly again.

Any ideas?